# Question on Fibration

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, fibration

Can anyone please help me with question?

Question: Let $p: E \rightarrow B$ be a fibration. Suppose there is a commuting diagram 
$$\begin{equation*}\begin{array}{ccl}
(\mathbb{I}\times\{0\}\bigcup\{0,1\} \times \mathbb{I}) \times X&\stackrel{H}{\longrightarrow}&E\\
\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!{\scriptstyle}\downarrow&&\downarrow{\scriptstyle p}\\
\!\!\!\!\mathbb{I} \times \mathbb{I} \times X&\stackrel{\phi}{\longrightarrow}&B
\end{array}\qquad\qquad\end{equation*}$$

Show that $\phi$ has a lift $\phi^\star$ to $E$ extending $H$.
Notation $\mathbb{I}= [0,1]$.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f:\mathbb{I}\times \{0\}\times X\rightarrow \mathbb{I}\times \mathbb{I}\times X$ and $g:\mathbb{I}\times \{0,1\}\times X\rightarrow \mathbb{I}\times \mathbb{I}\times X$ are weak cofibrations, if the diagram commutes, the following diagrams commute

$$\begin{equation*}\begin{array}{ccl}
(\{0,1\} \times \mathbb{I}) \times X&\stackrel{H}{\longrightarrow}&E\\
\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!{\scriptstyle}\downarrow&&\downarrow{\scriptstyle p}\\
\!\!\!\!\mathbb{I} \times \mathbb{I} \times X&\stackrel{\phi}{\longrightarrow}&B
\end{array}\qquad\qquad\end{equation*}$$

$$\begin{equation*}\begin{array}{ccl}
(\mathbb{I}\times\{0\} ) \times X&\stackrel{H}{\longrightarrow}&E\\
\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!{\scriptstyle}\downarrow&&\downarrow{\scriptstyle p}\\
\!\!\!\!\mathbb{I} \times \mathbb{I} \times X&\stackrel{\phi}{\longrightarrow}&B
\end{array}\qquad\qquad\end{equation*}$$

Since in a Quillen model, the class of maps which has the left lifting property in respect of the class of fibrations is the class of weak cofibrations, you can find a lift $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$ of the two previous diagrams which will enable you to construct $\phi^*$.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. @Tsemo could you please show me how to find a $phi_1$. I should be about to figure it out from there. This topic is just newly taught in class and I am struggling a bit with it.

Comment: The existence of $\phi_1$ is true in in a general model category in particular in Top.